# Issue With Repeating Statement In C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

(NOTE: This is an updated version of the question)
So I am upgrading the project I worked on previously.
Now, it prints the output of the program to a file, along with organizing grades.
So far, everything should work fine, except for one error.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Classes
{
    double acousticGuitarEnsemble;
    double biology;
    double english;
    double geometry;
    double hebrew;
    double jewishStudies;
    double worldHistory;
};

void grade1(Classes eitan)
{
    newGrade1:
    cout << "Which grade are you entering? (Use the following format: exampleFormat): ";
    string classBeingEntered1;
    cin >> classBeingEntered1;
    cout << "Enter the new grade: ";
    double grade1;
    cin >> grade1;
    cout << "Grade entered." << endl;
    if (classBeingEntered1 == "acousticGuitarEnsemble")
        eitan.acousticGuitarEnsemble = grade1;
    else if (classBeingEntered1 == "biology")
        eitan.biology = grade1;
    else if (classBeingEntered1 == "english")
        eitan.english = grade1;
    else if (classBeingEntered1 == "jewishStudies")
        eitan.jewishStudies = grade1;
    else if (classBeingEntered1 == "geometry")
        eitan.geometry = grade1;
    else if (classBeingEntered1 == "hebrew")
        eitan.hebrew = grade1;
    else if (classBeingEntered1 == "worldHistory")
        eitan.worldHistory = grade1;
    else
        cout << "Invalid class name. Try again." << endl;
        goto newGrade1;
}

void grade2(Classes eitan)
{
    newGrade2:
    cout << "Which grade are you entering? (Use the following format: exampleFormat): ";
    string classBeingEntered2;
    cin >> classBeingEntered2;
    cout << "Enter the new grade: ";
    double grade2;
    cin >> grade2;
    cout << "Grade entered." << endl;
    if (classBeingEntered2 == "acousticGuitarEnsemble")
        eitan.acousticGuitarEnsemble = grade2;
    else if (classBeingEntered2 == "biology")
        eitan.biology = grade2;
    else if (classBeingEntered2 == "english")
        eitan.english = grade2;
    else if (classBeingEntered2 == "jewishStudies")
        eitan.jewishStudies = grade2;
    else if (classBeingEntered2 == "geometry")
        eitan.geometry = grade2;
    else if (classBeingEntered2 == "hebrew")
        eitan.hebrew = grade2;
    else if (classBeingEntered2 == "worldHistory")
        eitan.worldHistory = grade2;
    else
        cout << "Invalid class name. Try again." << endl;
        goto newGrade2;
}

void grade3(Classes eitan)
{
    newGrade3:
    cout << "Which grade are you entering? (Use the following format: exampleFormat): ";
    string classBeingEntered3;
    cin >> classBeingEntered3;
    cout << "Enter the new grade: ";
    double grade3;
    cin >> grade3;
    cout << "Grade entered." << endl;
    if (classBeingEntered3 == "acousticGuitarEnsemble")
        eitan.acousticGuitarEnsemble = grade3;
    else if (classBeingEntered3 == "biology")
        eitan.biology = grade3;
    else if (classBeingEntered3 == "english")
        eitan.english = grade3;
    else if (classBeingEntered3 == "jewishStudies")
        eitan.jewishStudies = grade3;
    else if (classBeingEntered3 == "geometry")
        eitan.geometry = grade3;
    else if (classBeingEntered3 == "hebrew")
        eitan.hebrew = grade3;
    else if (classBeingEntered3 == "worldHistory")
        eitan.worldHistory = grade3;
    else
        cout << "Invalid class name. Try again." << endl;
        goto newGrade3;
}

void grade4(Classes eitan)
{
    newGrade4:
    cout << "Which grade are you entering? (Use the following format: exampleFormat): ";
    string classBeingEntered4;
    cin >> classBeingEntered4;
    cout << "Enter the new grade: ";
    double grade4;
    cin >> grade4;
    cout << "Grade entered." << endl;
    if (classBeingEntered4 == "acousticGuitarEnsemble")
        eitan.acousticGuitarEnsemble = grade4;
    else if (classBeingEntered4 == "biology")
        eitan.biology = grade4;
    else if (classBeingEntered4 == "english")
        eitan.english = grade4;
    else if (classBeingEntered4 == "jewishStudies")
        eitan.jewishStudies = grade4;
    else if (classBeingEntered4 == "geometry")
        eitan.geometry = grade4;
    else if (classBeingEntered4 == "hebrew")
        eitan.hebrew = grade4;
    else if (classBeingEntered4 == "worldHistory")
        eitan.worldHistory = grade4;
    else
        cout << "Invalid class name. Try again." << endl;
        goto newGrade4;
}

void grade5(Classes eitan)
{
    newGrade5:
    cout << "Which grade are you entering? (Use the following format: exampleFormat): ";
    string classBeingEntered5;
    cin >> classBeingEntered5;
    cout << "Enter the new grade: ";
    double grade5;
    cin >> grade5;
    cout << "Grade entered." << endl;
    if (classBeingEntered5 == "acousticGuitarEnsemble")
        eitan.acousticGuitarEnsemble = grade5;
    else if (classBeingEntered5 == "biology")
        eitan.biology = grade5;
    else if (classBeingEntered5 == "english")
        eitan.english = grade5;
    else if (classBeingEntered5 == "jewishStudies")
        eitan.jewishStudies = grade5;
    else if (classBeingEntered5 == "geometry")
        eitan.geometry = grade5;
    else if (classBeingEntered5 == "hebrew")
        eitan.hebrew = grade5;
    else if (classBeingEntered5 == "worldHistory")
        eitan.worldHistory = grade5;
    else
        cout << "Invalid class name. Try again." << endl;
        goto newGrade5;
}

void grade6(Classes eitan)
{
    newGrade6:
    cout << "Which grade are you entering? (Use the following format: exampleFormat): ";
    string classBeingEntered6;
    cin >> classBeingEntered6;
    cout << "Enter the new grade: ";
    double grade6;
    cin >> grade6;
    cout << "Grade entered." << endl;
    if (classBeingEntered6 == "acousticGuitarEnsemble")
        eitan.acousticGuitarEnsemble = grade6;
    else if (classBeingEntered6 == "biology")
        eitan.biology = grade6;
    else if (classBeingEntered6 == "english")
        eitan.english = grade6;
    else if (classBeingEntered6 == "jewishStudies")
        eitan.jewishStudies = grade6;
    else if (classBeingEntered6 == "geometry")
        eitan.geometry = grade6;
    else if (classBeingEntered6 == "hebrew")
        eitan.hebrew = grade6;
    else if (classBeingEntered6 == "worldHistory")
        eitan.worldHistory = grade6;
    else
        cout << "Invalid class name. Try again." << endl;
        goto newGrade6;
}

void grade7(Classes eitan)
{
    newGrade7:
    cout << "Which grade are you entering? (Use the following format: exampleFormat): ";
    string classBeingEntered7;
    cin >> classBeingEntered7;
    cout << "Enter the new grade: ";
    double grade7;
    cin >> grade7;
    cout << "Grade entered." << endl;
    if (classBeingEntered7 == "acousticGuitarEnsemble")
        eitan.acousticGuitarEnsemble = grade7;
    else if (classBeingEntered7 == "biology")
        eitan.biology = grade7;
    else if (classBeingEntered7 == "english")
        eitan.english = grade7;
    else if (classBeingEntered7 == "jewishStudies")
        eitan.jewishStudies = grade7;
    else if (classBeingEntered7 == "geometry")
        eitan.geometry = grade7;
    else if (classBeingEntered7 == "hebrew")
        eitan.hebrew = grade7;
    else if (classBeingEntered7 == "worldHistory")
        eitan.worldHistory = grade7;
    else
        cout << "Invalid class name. Try again." << endl;
        goto newGrade7;
}

Classes gradeEditor(Classes eitan)
{
    cout << "GradeBook 1.2" << endl;
    grade1(eitan);
    cout << "Editing next grade..." << endl;
    grade2(eitan);
    cout << "Editing next grade..." << endl;
    grade3(eitan);
    cout << "Editing next grade..." << endl;
    grade4(eitan);
    cout << "Editing next grade..." << endl;
    grade5(eitan);
    cout << "Editing next grade..." << endl;
    grade6(eitan);
    cout << "Entering next grade..." << endl;
    grade7(eitan);
    return eitan;
}

void choice(Classes eitan)
{
    choiceBack:
    cout << "Do you want to edit another grade? (If yes, you must reset all the grades) Press Y or N: ";
    char chChoice;
    cin >> chChoice;
    switch (chChoice) {
        case 'Y':
            cout << "Alright then!" << endl;
            do {
            gradeEditor(eitan);
            goto choiceBack; // Refers to beginning of choice() function
            } while (chChoice == 'Y');
        case 'N':
            cout << "Printing grades..." << endl;
            break;
        case 'y':
            cout << "Alright then!" << endl;
            do {
            gradeEditor(eitan);
            goto choiceBack; // Refers to beginning of choice() function
            } while (chChoice == 'y');
        case 'n':
            cout << "Printing grades..." << endl;
            break;
    }
}

void printGrades(Classes eitan)
{
    cout << "Acoustic Guitar Ensemble: " << eitan.acousticGuitarEnsemble << endl;
    cout << "Biology: " << eitan.biology << endl;
    cout << "English: " << eitan.english << endl;
    cout << "Jewish Studies: " << eitan.jewishStudies << endl;
    cout << "Geometry: " << eitan.geometry << endl;
    cout << "Hebrew: " << eitan.hebrew << endl;
    cout << "World History: " << eitan.worldHistory << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}

int main(Classes eitan)
{
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("userGrades.txt");
    gradeEditor(eitan);
    choice(eitan);
    printGrades(eitan);
    outputFile.close();
    cout << "Grades saved to file!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In Classes gradeEditor(), I am entering in 7 grades.
However, it doesn't stop after 7 times.
Anyone see how to fix that?
- Eitan
P.S: I know that people have an issue with me using goto. But I haven't figured out a way to use a do while in there for those specific circumstances yet. So don't mention it unless you can tell me a better replacement for it.
**P.P.S:** At this point, I was not well aware of how I could better format my program correctly. I did understand programming syntax so well, but I do now.

Comment: Those `goto`s should be loops.

Comment: None of your `gradeX` functions ever return!  They just `goto` in loops forever!

Comment: And, there's no communication between `gradeEditor()` and any of the `gradeX()` functions.  What are they supposed to return?

Comment: You haven't touched `eitan` before returning it. You keep declaring local variables and throwing them away.

Comment: @JoeZ They should return the number entered for the grade

Comment: You could add a default constructor to the `Classes` class, but really that is the least of the problems with this code.

Comment: @chris Unless you are suggesting that I change the scope of the variables to global, I don't see how what you just said is going to help.

Comment: You're declaring local variables over and over again and never returning them. For instance, in gradeEditor you declare `eitan`, never do anything to it (in each function you call, they have their own copy, which they also discard) and then try to return it.

Comment: Just for a start, instead of grade1 to grade7, just have 1 grade method: `grade(Classes& class)`, and instead of declaring a local variable, use `class` that gets passed in.

Comment: Can I suggest naming your struct `Courses` rather than `Classes`?

Comment: @nhgrif The name of the struct is irrelevant at the moment.

Comment: I know.  But it's confusing.

Comment: @splrs So are you suggesting that I use references? If so, how can I write the code so I can do this?

Comment: @nhgrif I am choosing to name the struct as so. If you ever want to name a struct Courses in one of your own programs, go right ahead. But for now, I'm going to call mine Classes.

Comment: It's not just a matter of what I'd call my variables.  I don't care if you call it `Courses` or not.  That was merely a suggestion.  The problem is that `Classes` makes your code confusing to read because of how close it is to a C++ reserved word, `class`.  You can name your variables whatever you want (other than reserved words), and the variable name has no bearing on performance.  The only thing a variable name effects is readability.  As such, variable names should be chosen with the idea of optimizing readability in mind.

Comment: Still broken after the edit.  You need to pass a reference otherwise you're editing a copy of the variable you passed, and none of your `goto` loops seem to end.

Comment: Don't overwrite the original question in your edits.  If you need to ask a new question, ask a new question.  If you need additional clarification on the current question, edit in more info (without overwriting the original question/code).

Comment: @nhgrif I actually didn't think about class. I'll change that.

Comment: @RetiredNinja So do I do something such as (Courses& eitan)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is extraordinarily clear.  The problem is not with the `return` keyword.  The problem is trying to use a variable without initializing it.

```
Classes eitan;
//several lines of code in which you do nothing with eitan, then:
return eitan;
```

You'd run into the same error message if you tried doing other things besides `return`.

If you need to use the `eitan` declared in `main`, then pass it as a variable.

```
Classes gradeEditor(Classes& c) {
    //stuff
    return c;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
gradeEditor(eitan);
```

And do the same for all your `void` functions.

If you don't want to pass the variable around, but want to use it in multiple functions, then you must declare it as a global variable.  Simply creating a new variable that happens to have the same name in different scopes doesn't make the two variables point to the same information.

---

You're stuck in infinite loops because:

```
else
    cout << "Invalid class name. Try again." << endl;
    goto newGrade2;
```

doesn't do what you think it does.  You need curly braces:

```
else {
    cout << "Invalid class name. Try again." << endl;
    goto newGrade2;
}
```

Comment: Well, this is what everyone is missing. I DO use Classes eitan, because I am editing variables in the struct in each function. I'm just dividing it into separate functions, to organize it better.

Comment: What?  Who is missing what?

Comment: @DJHead-On, You're editing variables in *different objects*. If objects that had the same name and were defined locally in different functions were actually all the same object, code would become extremely unmaintainable.

Comment: @chris I did have it like that at first, but I fixed that (if I understand what you're getting at).

Comment: @chris Not any less maintainable than 7 functions that all do the same thing or `goto:` statements... ;)

Comment: @DJHead-On I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite your code and remove all goto's, it is considered
bad practice - at least in the kind of program you are doing.

You could rewrite the `choice` function like this, notice also that the
`Classes` is passed by reference allowing it do modified. By passing it
by reference you can modify it and this is something you should
do in all functions where you modify it, otherwise the changes will 
remain local since you are passing a copy to the function

```
#include <cctype> // for std::toupper

void choice(Classes& eitan) // pass by reference to modify argument
{
  do
  {
    cout << "Do you want to edit another grade? (If yes, you must reset all the grades) Press Y or N: ";
    char chChoice;
    cin >> chChoice;
    chChoice = std::toupper(chChoice);
    switch (chChoice) 
    {
      case 'Y':
          cout << "Alright then!" << endl;
          gradeEditor(eitan);
          break;
      case 'N':
          cout << "Printing grades..." << endl;
          break;
      default:
          cout << "Please answer Y or N!" << endl;
          break;
    }
  }
  while ( chChoice != 'N' );
}
```

Comment: What is std::toupper going to do to help? What exactly is its syntax?